# Chromium Annoying New Feature

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I used to have an email notifier extension icon in my toolbar at the top right. As of Google Chromium 10.0.648.204 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS, they have since replaced the toolbar extension system with a popdown menu, and I can't see my Gmail notifier icon anymore unless I click that, which kind of defeats the purpose of it.

I had no idea that Google would roll this out and how detrimental it would be to my preferences. What gives?

How can I change this setting?

Comment: How about a screenshot, it is not that way on my W7 PC, same version Chrome.

Comment: @Moab, see grawity's screenshot because he shows it well and solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button area is resizable using the mouse. Point to the gray area between address bar and first button, and drag.

[image: (Examples)]

Comment: You are so awesome! I had no idea that this existed! And it was so hard to find this information on the web. More people need to see this documented.

Comment: I should add that the buttons can be reordered by dragging them, too.